# Insert the contents of one list into another list at a specific index

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have two list

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7]
```

I want to insert the contents of list2 into the `2`-th index of `list1` to get the result

```
list1 = [1,2,6,7,3,4,5]
```

I've tried:

`list1.insert(2,list2)` gives `[1,2,[6,7],3,4,5]`

```
temp = list1[:2]
temp.extend(list2)
temp.extend(list1[2:])
print(temp)
```

but it seems not a good way

does any way can do like this

```
list1.insert(2,extend(list2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = [6,7]
>>> list1[2:2] = list2
>>> list1
[1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5]
```